# Tricky query: Get average only of latest records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models:

```
Supplier
  |
Price - Book
  |
PriceType
```

Price is the joint table for the other three models.

Every month, the latest Prices get collected. As a consequence, every Book / Supplier / PriceType combination has multiple Prices, collected at different points in time. Only the last Price for this combination is the Price I'm interested in.

I now want to know, what is the average Price over all Books for a particular PriceType / Supplier combination, ignoring all prices except the last Price for that particular combination.

Is there a way to do this on the database (Postgres) level rather than writing something terribly slow like this:

```
prices = []    
Supplier.first.books.each do |book|
  latest_price_for_book = Price.joins(:price_type, :book).where("price_types.id = ? AND books.id = ?", PriceType.first, book).last
  prices << latest_price_for_book.price
end
average = prices.sum / prices.size.to_f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you're using the `book` variable. And your code is a little different than your explanation. Anyways, you can use aggregation functions for a faster results.

```
Price
  .where("price_types.id = ? AND suppliers.id = ? AND books.id = ?", 
    @price_type, @supplier, @book)
  .average(:<column_with_price>)
```

If you want an average price for each book, you'll just have to `group by` the book id.

Comment: For each Book, I only want to use the latest price and then get an average on a particular PriceType / Supplier combination.

Comment: I corrected the code so it uses the book variable as intended.